Error establishing a database connection wordpress
I get this error intermittently in my WordPress website hosted on Digital Ocean with a LiteSpeed server. When the site works, it's just fine, but when it doesn't work it keeps giving this error for few minute.

Error establishing a database connection This either means that the
username and password information in your wp-config.php file is
incorrect or that contact with the database server at localhost could
not be established. This could mean your host’s database server is
down.
Are you sure you have the correct username and password? Are you sure
you have typed the correct hostname? Are you sure the database server
is running?


When the issue occurs, could you please share the output of the top command from the SSH console along with the MySQL service status?
